# Suspension in chat on more than one site

Tags: bug, chat, account-suspension

I have been suspended on [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), and that includes a suspension on the meta and presumably the chat. However, surely I should be able to chat on others sites such as Area 51 or Stack Overflow? Yet when I went onto the Area 51 chat earlier, it told me that I wasn't allowed to chat because

> your account is suspended on the parent site and cannot chat for 14 days.

My chat account is [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/274572/user00001) and you may notice that it says the same message. What should I do? Surely I should be allowed to chat in non-PPCG rooms?

Comment: Tip: associate your chat account with the SE site whose mods & policies you like at most.

Comment: Btw, don't worry on that, 1.5 months is nothing. The codegolf is a friendly site in my opinion, I don't know what you did, but in their case, an ordinary polite behavior is enough for the longterm survival.

Comment: What? You requested your own suspension? Why?

Comment: What affected your code?

Comment: I am sorry, but I think you have serious problems to explain anything meaningfully. My suggestion would be to invest more effort into the school and lesser into the internet.

Answer (score 4):

If your parent site account is suspended, you're suspended on chat everywhere.

The simple solution is *don't get suspended*.

Since all sites share the same chat server (and moderators in theory have moderation abilities throughout most of chat.se). Quite often bad behavior on the main site is followed by bad behavior on chat.

I do admit its a little odd if you got suspended on *another* site and get treated differently, but I suppose this might be a call for chat suspension no matter where you get suspended, rather than the other way around.

Comment: Shog replied something very similar in the dupe.

Comment: ... exact same words too... I totally deny being another Shog clone ;p

Comment: hehe, I was trying to hint it's better to close this as dupe than have dupe answers. :-)

Comment: I guess. I'll throw in a closevote then

Comment: "The simple solution is *don't get suspended*" I would just like to point out that **I requested the suspension**.

Comment: @user00001 Workaround identified: don't request suspension.

Comment: Nit-pick: Not *all* sites share the same chat server. SO and meta.SE have their own.

Comment: Well, for SU we've generally had an unofficial policy of denying requests for  suspensions partially cause of situations like this. The only real workaround is to get unsuspended, switch your parent site and be resuspended, but it does feel like it wouldn't help an underlying lack of self control